# Палити чи курити?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Наслухавшись реклам, завжди думала, що правильно "палити", але нещодавно знайомий сказав, що це неправильно і його вчителька з української мови завжди наголошувала, що правильно казати "курити". В інтернеті думки розходяться. Наприклад, в Академічному словнику http://sum.in.ua/s/kuryty зазначено, що "курити" є нормативним словом, коли йдеться про цигарки. То чи термін "паління" є штучно нав'язаним ЗМІ?Яке з цих слів підходить для окреслення шкідливої звички?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обидва слова є нормативними. Жодне не є нав'язаним ЗМІ. Обидва можна з додатком (*курити/палити щось*) і без додатка.

Словники:

- [«курити»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46203&page=1458) в «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах (нас цікавить значення 1);
- [«палити»](http://sum.in.ua/s/palyty) в «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах (нас цікавить значення 5).

Цитати:

- «Із Лисянки Кругом засвітило: Ото Ґонта з Залізняком, Люльки закурили. Страшно, страшно закурили. І в пеклі не вміють Отак курить» (Т. Шевченко);
- «Жили собі спокійненько: білявий чоловік або огонь кресав, або люльку палив» (Марко Вовчок).

Фактично на мою думку, «палити» узагальнюється до «примусити щось горіти», а «курити» — до «примусити щось диміти».

Мовознавці/популяризатори:

- Борис Антоненко-Давидович [каже](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53402/33269.html), що слова (в обговорюваному значенні) тотожні, але рекомендує слово «курити» через меншу кількість його значень;
- Анатолій Васянович [каже](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqCTj3mumqk), що слова (в обговорюваному значенні) синонімічні й обидва правильні (за його словами: «курити» більше вживають у східних областях, а «палити» у західних, причому обговорюване значення останнього прийшло з польської);
- Олександр Авраменко [каже](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GqiE2wYEQ0), що слова (в обговорюваному значенні) синонімічні й обидва правильні, але рекомендує слово «курити» через більший розмір гнізда однокорінних слів із обговорюваним значенням (*палій* — уже інше значення, а *курець* — усе ще те).

Answer (score -3):

Колись мала нагоду поспілкуватись з п. Іриною Фаріон. Отож вона наголосила, що правильно вживати "курити". До того ж навела приклад: можна спалити хату, а цигарки курять! :-)

Comment: З одного боку, це цікаво, адже Ірина Фаріон (незалежно від нашого ставлення до її поглядів) — доктор філологічних наук. Але з іншого, було б краще, якби Ви навели посилання на якісь загальнодоступні джерела, де видно, що вона це стверджує, адже, при всій повазі до Вас, те, що Ви кажете, неможливо перевірити. Тим більше, що невідомо, в якому контексті вона це казала: одне діло — коли люди спілкуються і висловлюють неперевірені думки (від яких можуть потім відмовитися або які можуть узагалі забути), а інше — коли люди свідомо виступають чи публікуються.